# babel-cli vs babel-preset-es2015 vs babel-register vs babel-core?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

What are all these babel dependencies? What are each of them for and how do they differ? Which one should I use for my nodejs web app?

I have looked on the API website but is there any guide that puts these into simple human English?

Answer (score 6):

In simple terms:

- [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/): Is the one you would use if you were trying to
  compile an ES6/ES7 module to ES5- and you had a need to do that via a
  terminal command.
- [babel-preset-es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/): Is the package containing
  a subset of features that ES6/ES7 provides.
- [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/): A
  require that you do and causes every file require there after to run
  through babel, thus allowing you to write ES6/ES7 code in every module.
- [babel-core](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/): Same as "babel-cli" except you would use it programmatically inside your app.

Basically, you could use "babel-register" during development with the "babel-preset-es2015" package set. Then use "babel-cli" or "babel-core" to compile your files before production.

I hope that helps.